# How to set variable values while debugging in Visual Code using PHP debug?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug, setvalue

I'm wondering how to set values of variables that I can see at a breakpoint while debugging in Visual Code. 
I'm using Version 1.20.1.

I just can't press on Set Variable.[image]

Answer (score 37):

You need to use the DEBUG CONSOLE, and put the variable and the value:

```
$variable = "value"
```

[image: Example $variable = "value"]

Comment: You can open the console with Ctrl+Shift+Y and drag it next to the terminal tab via your mouse